# Me aparecen iconos duplicados en uikit

Tags: html, css, uikit-3

Estoy haciendo una página de mi curriculum para poder tener una presentación en versión web. Para ello, estoy usando el framework [uikit 3](https://getuikit.com/).

Estaba intentando hacer el efecto parallax en los grid de datos, por ello, he agregado jQuery para que todo funcionara correctamente. El problema viene en  que se dibujan los iconos en svg por duplicado.

Código:

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/uikit/3.0.0-beta.1/css/uikit.css" />
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto" rel="stylesheet">

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/uikit/3.0.0-beta.40/js/uikit.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/uikit/3.0.0-beta.40/js/uikit-icons.js"></script>



<div class="uk-card-footer uk-text-center uk-padding">
  <a uk-icon="ratio: 2; icon: twitter" class="uk-icon uk-text-primary uk-margin-right uk-margin-left" href="https://twitter.com/FNC_Soul">
    <svg width="40" height="40" viewBox="0 0 20 20" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" ratio="2">
      <path d="M19,4.74 C18.339,5.029 17.626,5.229 16.881,5.32 C17.644,4.86 18.227,4.139 18.503,3.28 C17.79,3.7 17.001,4.009 16.159,4.17 C15.485,3.45 14.526,3 13.464,3 C11.423,3 9.771,4.66 9.771,6.7 C9.771,6.99 9.804,7.269 9.868,7.539 C6.795,7.38 4.076,5.919 2.254,3.679 C1.936,4.219 1.754,4.86 1.754,5.539 C1.754,6.82 2.405,7.95 3.397,8.61 C2.79,8.589 2.22,8.429 1.723,8.149 L1.723,8.189 C1.723,9.978 2.997,11.478 4.686,11.82 C4.376,11.899 4.049,11.939 3.713,11.939 C3.475,11.939 3.245,11.919 3.018,11.88 C3.49,13.349 4.852,14.419 6.469,14.449 C5.205,15.429 3.612,16.019 1.882,16.019 C1.583,16.019 1.29,16.009 1,15.969 C2.635,17.019 4.576,17.629 6.662,17.629 C13.454,17.629 17.17,12 17.17,7.129 C17.17,6.969 17.166,6.809 17.157,6.649 C17.879,6.129 18.504,5.478 19,4.74">
      </path>
    </svg>
  </a>
  <a uk-icon="ratio: 2; icon: github" class="uk-icon uk-text-primary uk-margin-right uk-margin-left" href="https://github.com/SoulApps">
    <svg width="40" height="40" viewBox="0 0 20 20" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" ratio="2">
      <path d="M10,1 C5.03,1 1,5.03 1,10 C1,13.98 3.58,17.35 7.16,18.54 C7.61,18.62 7.77,18.34 7.77,18.11 C7.77,17.9 7.76,17.33 7.76,16.58 C5.26,17.12 4.73,15.37 4.73,15.37 C4.32,14.33 3.73,14.05 3.73,14.05 C2.91,13.5 3.79,13.5 3.79,13.5 C4.69,13.56 5.17,14.43 5.17,14.43 C5.97,15.8 7.28,15.41 7.79,15.18 C7.87,14.6 8.1,14.2 8.36,13.98 C6.36,13.75 4.26,12.98 4.26,9.53 C4.26,8.55 4.61,7.74 5.19,7.11 C5.1,6.88 4.79,5.97 5.28,4.73 C5.28,4.73 6.04,4.49 7.75,5.65 C8.47,5.45 9.24,5.35 10,5.35 C10.76,5.35 11.53,5.45 12.25,5.65 C13.97,4.48 14.72,4.73 14.72,4.73 C15.21,5.97 14.9,6.88 14.81,7.11 C15.39,7.74 15.73,8.54 15.73,9.53 C15.73,12.99 13.63,13.75 11.62,13.97 C11.94,14.25 12.23,14.8 12.23,15.64 C12.23,16.84 12.22,17.81 12.22,18.11 C12.22,18.35 12.38,18.63 12.84,18.54 C16.42,17.35 19,13.98 19,10 C19,5.03 14.97,1 10,1 L10,1 Z">
      </path>
    </svg>
  </a>
  <a uk-icon="ratio: 2; icon: linkedin" class="uk-icon uk-text-primary uk-margin-right uk-margin-left" href="https://www.linkedin.com/in/ramonguardialopez/">
    <svg width="40" height="40" viewBox="0 0 20 20" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" ratio="2">
      <path d="M5.77,17.89 L5.77,7.17 L2.21,7.17 L2.21,17.89 L5.77,17.89 L5.77,17.89 Z M3.99,5.71 C5.23,5.71 6.01,4.89 6.01,3.86 C5.99,2.8 5.24,2 4.02,2 C2.8,2 2,2.8 2,3.85 C2,4.88 2.77,5.7 3.97,5.7 L3.99,5.7 L3.99,5.71 L3.99,5.71 Z"></path> <path d="M7.75,17.89 L11.31,17.89 L11.31,11.9 C11.31,11.58 11.33,11.26 11.43,11.03 C11.69,10.39 12.27,9.73 13.26,9.73 C14.55,9.73 15.06,10.71 15.06,12.15 L15.06,17.89 L18.62,17.89 L18.62,11.74 C18.62,8.45 16.86,6.92 14.52,6.92 C12.6,6.92 11.75,7.99 11.28,8.73 L11.3,8.73 L11.3,7.17 L7.75,7.17 C7.79,8.17 7.75,17.89 7.75,17.89 L7.75,17.89 L7.75,17.89 Z"></path>
    </svg>
  </a>
  <a uk-icon="ratio: 2; icon: mail" class="uk-icon uk-text-primary uk-margin-right uk-margin-left" href="mailto:ramon.guardialopez@gmail.com">
    <svg width="40" height="40" viewBox="0 0 20 20" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" ratio="2">
      <polyline fill="none" stroke="#000" points="1.4,6.5 10,11 18.6,6.5"></polyline>
      <path d="M 1,4 1,16 19,16 19,4 1,4 Z M 18,15 2,15 2,5 18,5 18,15 Z"></path>
    </svg>
  </a>
</div>
```

¿Alguien sabría decirme por qué los iconos aparecen duplicados?

---

Después de investigar mucho, al quitar el `icon: name` (p.e. `icon: twitter`) de uk-icon se solventa.  Sigo sin saber por qué, pero esta es la solución. ¿Alguien sabe por qué?

Comment: Ha sido rápido, pero después de investigar mucho, al quitar el icon:name de uk-icon se solventa. 

Sigo sin saber por qué, pero esta es la solución.

¿Alguien sabe por qué?

Comment: ¿Dónde está `icon:name`?

Comment: En cada uno de los enlaces de los iconos 

EJ: <a uk-icon="ratio: 2; icon: twitter" class="uk-icon

Si quito icon:twitter se solventa.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

En uikit, cuando le pones `icon: name` (p.e. `icon: twitter`) a un elemento, se va a insertar automáticamente el icono especificado en SVG (usan los iconos de Font Awesome por lo que pone en la documentación).

Aparece dos veces porque estás duplicando el icono: por una parte usas `icon: twitter` que va a poner el icono de twitter, y luego dentro del enlace pones el SVG del icono de twitter. Uno de los dos sobra. Puedes quitar el `icon: name` como sugieres en tu pregunta, y otra opción sería dejarlo y quitar el SVG que hay dentro del enlace (lo cual reducirá el código de la página y la hará más legible... aunque eso puede ser cuestión de opiniones):

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/uikit/3.0.0-beta.1/css/uikit.css" />
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto" rel="stylesheet">

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/uikit/3.0.0-beta.40/js/uikit.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/uikit/3.0.0-beta.40/js/uikit-icons.js"></script>



<div class="uk-card-footer uk-text-center uk-padding">
  <a uk-icon="ratio: 2; icon: twitter" class="uk-icon uk-text-primary uk-margin-right uk-margin-left" href="https://twitter.com/FNC_Soul"></a>
  <a uk-icon="ratio: 2; icon: github" class="uk-icon uk-text-primary uk-margin-right uk-margin-left" href="https://github.com/SoulApps"></a>
  <a uk-icon="ratio: 2; icon: linkedin" class="uk-icon uk-text-primary uk-margin-right uk-margin-left" href="https://www.linkedin.com/in/ramonguardialopez/"></a>
  <a uk-icon="ratio: 2; icon: mail" class="uk-icon uk-text-primary uk-margin-right uk-margin-left" href="mailto:ramon.guardialopez@gmail.com"></a>
</div>
```

Comment: De acuerdo. El código que usé para los iconos es el que venía en el ejemplo de Uikit. Voy a probar a quitar los svg. Así el código es menor y más legible. Muchas gracias.

Edit: Problema resuelto haciendo esto. Gracias.

Answer (score 0):

Ya veo que lo has solucionado pero tiene pinta de ser algún tipo de bug. Aquí lo comentan y lo solucionan añadiendo comillas simples:

https://github.com/uikit/uikit/issues/2886

```
<a uk-icon="'ratio: 2; icon: twitter'"
```

He probado en tu solución y funciona

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 0):

Prueba quitando las etiquetas `<path>` y  `<svg>` este es el resultado:

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/uikit/3.0.0-beta.1/css/uikit.css" />
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto" rel="stylesheet">

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/uikit/3.0.0-beta.40/js/uikit.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/uikit/3.0.0-beta.40/js/uikit-icons.js"></script>



<div class="uk-card-footer uk-text-center uk-padding">
  <a uk-icon="ratio: 2; icon: twitter" class="uk-icon uk-text-primary uk-margin-right uk-margin-left" href="https://twitter.com/FNC_Soul">
    
  </a>
  <a uk-icon="ratio: 2; icon: github" class="uk-icon uk-text-primary uk-margin-right uk-margin-left" href="https://github.com/SoulApps">
    
  </a>
  <a uk-icon="ratio: 2; icon: linkedin" class="uk-icon uk-text-primary uk-margin-right uk-margin-left" href="https://www.linkedin.com/in/ramonguardialopez/">
    
  </a>
  <a uk-icon="ratio: 2; icon: mail" class="uk-icon uk-text-primary uk-margin-right uk-margin-left" href="mailto:ramon.guardialopez@gmail.com">
   
  </a>
</div>
```